# What's wrong with my camera collision in A-Frame

Tags: aframe

I'm copying straight from the A-Frame documentation on [RayCaster](https://aframe.io/docs/0.4.0/components/raycaster.html#properties) but I'm still not getting it right. I want the collider to occur when the camera connects with the cube.

Here's the [github link](https://github.com/ybinstock/Platos-Cave) for context.

```
  <a-entity geometry="primitive: box" class="collidable"
            position="1 2.5 0"></a-entity>



AFRAME.registerComponent('collider-check', {
    dependencies: ['raycaster'],
    init: function () {
      this.el.addEventListener('raycaster-intersected', function () {
        console.log('Player hit something!');
      });
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

`raycaster-intersected` event is a ray from camera to cursor position, if the ray hit something, it will trigger `raycaster-intersected` event. `collider` event is more like checking distance between camera and something collidable, you can look at this component [sphere-collider.js](https://github.com/donmccurdy/aframe-extras/blob/master/src/misc/sphere-collider.js) then, register your own `collider-check` component.